# Summing values in an Iterator

Tags: python

Below code prints the desired output - 10

```
values = iter(range(1, 5))
sum(values)
```

Whereas if I add one more line of code between these lines, output changes to 0

```
values = iter(range(1, 5))
values_list = list(values)
sum(values)
```

Comment: If you exhaust the iterator with `list(values)` then there are no elements left for `sum`.

Comment: The iterator is exhausted when you do `list()` on it.

Comment: Iterators are one time use objects, once you have performed an operation on them they are emptied. So when you do a list(values), the "values" iterator has no data. Now When you sum(values) , sum(0) = 0. Though you can still use sum(values_list) to get the sum

Answer (score 1):

Python `iterators` are *exhaustable* objects, meaning that they are used them up as you call them.

- 1<sup>rst</sup> example:

  ```
  values = iter(range(1, 5))  # <- iterator is created
  sum(values)                 # <- all of it is used at once
  ```
- 2<sup>nd</sup> example:

  ```
  values = iter(range(1, 5))  # <- iterator is created
  values_list = list(values)  # <- all of it is used at once
  sum(values)                 # <- nothing left to sum :(
  ```

If you want to use something over and over again, the `iterator` data type is not the one for you; use a `list` instead.