# Why are some (but not all) Python iterators summable after being exhausted?

Tags: python, iterator

In Python, iterators are intended for one-time use.  Once an iterator has raised StopIteration, it shouldn't return any more values.  Yet if I define a custom iterator, it seems that I can still sum the values after they're exhausted!

Example code (Python 3.6.5, or replace `__next__(self)` with `next(self)` to see the same behaviour in Python 2.7.15):

```
class CustomIterator:
  def __iter__(self):
    self.n=0
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    self.n += 1
    if self.n > 3:
      raise StopIteration
    return self.n

i1 = iter([1,2,3])
i2 = iter(CustomIterator())

print('Sum of i1 is {}'.format(sum(i1))) # returns 6 as expected
print('Sum of i1 is {}'.format(sum(i1))) # returns 0 because i1 is now exhausted
try:
  print(next(i1))
except StopIteration:
  print("i1 has raised StopIteration") # this exception happens
print('Sum of i1 is {}'.format(sum(i1))) # 0 again

print('Sum of i2 is {}'.format(sum(i2))) # returns 6 as expected
print('Sum of i2 is {}'.format(sum(i2))) # returns 6 again!
try:
  print(next(i2))
except StopIteration:
  print("i2 has raised StopIteration") # still get an exception
print('Sum of i2 is {}'.format(sum(i2))) # and yet we get 6 again
```

Why do i1 and i2 behave differently?  Is it some trick in how `sum` is implemented?  I've checked https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum and it doesn't give me a lot to go on.

Related questions:

- [Summing values in an Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55567383/summing-values-in-an-iterator)
- [Why can't I iterate twice over the same data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data)
- [Python iterator is empty after performing some action on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039334/python-iterator-is-empty-after-performing-some-action-on-it)

These describe the expected behaviour for built-in iterators, but don't explain why my custom iterator behaves differently.

Comment: Figured out the answer half way through typing the question!  But I'm happy for other people to add their own, more informative, answers :-)

Comment: Because you are *manually resetting*: `self.n=0` in `__iter__`.

Comment: Very well asked question, and good job sharing the results of your research and analysis. I wouldn't be surprised to dupe-hammer other questions with this in the future. That said, nowadays I would rather take the approach of implementing `__iter__` with a generator, rather than writing a separate `__next__`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, thanks for teaching me the word "dupe-hammer"!

Comment: See also e.g. https://treyhunner.com/2018/06/how-to-make-an-iterator-in-python/ for several alternative approaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the custom iterator is initialising inside the `__iter__` method.  Even though `i2 = iter(CustomIterator())` includes an explicit call to `iter`, the `sum` function (and also `min`, `max`, `for`, etc) will still call `i2.__iter__()` again and reset `i2`.

There's a bunch of tutorials out there on "how to make Python iterators", and about half of them say something like "to make an iterator, you just have to define `iter` and `next` methods".  While this is technically correct as per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types), it will get you into trouble sometimes.  In many cases you'll also want a separate `__init__` method to initialise the iterator.

So to fix this problem, redefine `CustomIterator` as:

```
class CustomIterator:
  def __init__(self):
    self.n=0

  def __iter__(self):
    return self

  def __next__(self):
    self.n += 1
    if self.n > 3:
      raise StopIteration
    return self.n

i1 = iter([1,2,3])
i2 = CustomIterator() ### iter(...) is not needed here (but won't do any harm either)
```

Then `init` is called once and once only on creating a new iterator, and repeated calls to `iter` won't reset the iterator.

Comment: *"This is not strictly correct"* - Actually it really is.

Comment: @don't talk just code, can you explain a little more?  Can you suggest a better way to phrase that sentence?  Thanks.

Comment: Well, those two methods are exactly what's required for iterators, see the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types). Maybe something like "Practically, you'll also want an `__init__` method or other way to initialise the iterator".